# Connecting Access to C# using OleDb

Tags: c#, database, oledbconnection

How would you use an OleDbConnection and is it better than using the framework provided by .NET?

Comment: The question is too broad. Show us your effort and code you've came up with so far. Feel free to ask on how to solve a problem, but right now you're asking how to make the whole app in general.

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question.  What have you tried? What don't you understand? Are you asking how to connect to a database? How to write SQL? How to interact with a label? How to generate a random number?

Comment: Isn't a database overkill for storing a set of words? isn't a simple text file enough ?

Comment: @SLaks it is now edited

Comment: @SteveB its `Access` its both over kill and underkill at the same time. Wildly difficult to use, but completely underpowered. The OleDbConnector only exists for people who have legacy `Access` databases.

Comment: @SteveB is there no other way of doing this?

Comment: Have you looked at the `Random` class?

Comment: Why don't you just use a text file with one word per line?

Answer (score 0):

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection("Connection String"))
{   
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from tbl", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        //do database stuff
    }
}
```

this is a basic construct for most data connections
here I used oracle
you can replace oracle with OleDb, Ibm.Iseries, SQL Server .....